# How to prevent Visual Studio from creating "Properties" folder?

Tags: visual-studio

The default "AssemblyInfo" goes in there, but I dont need it for our directory structure. Every time I delete the "Properties" folder inside my project, it gets recreated on reload. How to prevent that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Open the project file from the OS side and remove the Properties folder node: `<AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>`

Comment: With Visual Studio 2015 this is not enough any more - see Mike's answer below for the full process.

Answer (score 21):

First:

Open the solution and make sure you don't have the file "AssemblyInfo.cs" in the Properties folder.
If you do move it to the root of the project. Save Solution and close Visual Studio.

Second:

Open the project file (*.csproj) with a text editor like [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) and search and remove these two entries:

```
<AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
```

and

```
<ItemGroup>
<Folder Include="Properties\" />
</ItemGroup>
```

then save the project file and reopen the Solution in VS.
That should do the trick.

Regards,
Mike

Comment: I am trying to remove it from Visual Studio 2015 and there is now `.xproj` and there is not a setting value name: `Properties` anywhere. so how to fix it?

Comment: You can also edit the project file directly within Visual Studio. Right click on the project and choose Unload Project. Then right-click again and choose "Edit". This will open the project file XML with syntax highlighting etc. When you finish, save the file, right click on the project in Solution Explorer again and choose Reload Project.